# How can I add a separator in menu dropbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add to my dropdown menu a separator so I use this code:

```
<li class='divider'></li>
```

This is my html code with separator:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="ul_menu">
  <li>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="checkbox" name="aggiungidsfsdf" checked=""> dsfsdf
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><i class="fa fa-universal-access fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="checkbox" name="aggiungiasdas"> asdas
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><i class="fa fa-universal-access fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="checkbox" name="aggiungicollaborativo"> collaborativo
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><i class="fa fa fa-users fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="checkbox" name="aggiungiprivato"> privato
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="checkbox" name="aggiungicollabborativo"> collabborativo
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><i class="fa fa fa-users fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  </li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="aggiungi_bookmarked"><i class="fa fa-fw fa fa-plus"></i>Aggiungi Bookmarked</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But this code doesn't work because I don't see separator. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Seprator in where? Show html that you want completely.

Comment: I have run your code through an [HTML formatter](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html) to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You have issue in your code `'`is extra added after li.

```css
ul, li{list-style:none}
.divider{border-bottom:1px solid red}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="ul_menu">
  <li><div class="col-md-10"><input type="checkbox" name="aggiungidsfsdf" checked="">   dsfsdf</div><div class="col-md-2"><i class="fa fa-universal-access fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></li>
  <li><div class="col-md-10"><input type="checkbox" name="aggiungiasdas">      asdas</div><div class="col-md-2"><i class="fa fa-universal-access fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></li>
  <li><div class="col-md-10"><input type="checkbox" name="aggiungicollaborativo">       collaborativo</div><div class="col-md-2"><i class="fa fa fa-users fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></li>
  <li><div class="col-md-10"><input type="checkbox" name="aggiungiprivato">     privato</div><div class="col-md-2"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></li><li><div class="col-md-10"><input type="checkbox" name="aggiungicollabborativo">        collabborativo</div><div class="col-md-2"><i class="fa fa fa-users fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></li>
  <li class="divider"></li'><li><a href="#" id="aggiungi_bookmarked"><i class="fa fa-fw fa fa-plus"></i>Aggiungi Bookmarked</a></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you android programming ? if yes,you can go to xml file find the **listview**and add this line
          `android:divider:#ffffffff`

`"#ffffffff"` can be replaced by the the hex code of any colors that you like